# Cannot click checkbox though the webelement can be seen and assigned

Tags: java, selenium, checkbox, webdriver

Tried both .click() and .sendKeys(Keys.SPACE)

```
WebElement pageElement = driver.findElement(by);

String whatTha = pageElement.getAttribute("id");

System.out.println("Element's Attribute is " + whatTha);
System.out.println("Add Witness, by is " + by);
pageElement.sendKeys(Keys.SPACE);
System.out.println("Space key sent to element");
```

Response:

Element's Attribute is fSkipAddEntity

Add Witness, by is By.id: fSkipAddEntity

Space key sent to element

Also tried using JavascriptExecutor, with same result ...

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", pageElement );
```

Comment: Can you provide html?

Comment: Without HTML, There is no chances to provide solution.

Comment: Do you get any exception? If yes, what exception? Did you tried: WebElement pageElement = driver.findElement(CORRECT LOCATOR);pageElement.click();?

Comment: <div id="formItems">
            <div id="addWitnessQuesSect" class="addItemSelection">
               <label style="font-weight: bold;">Add witness: </label>
               <input name="fSkipAddEntity" type="checkbox" id="fSkipAddEntity" onclick="checkAddEntityQuestion()" /><label>No</label>
            </div>
            <div id="claimPartySect" class="copyFromSect">

Comment: No exception thrown. As the above shows, the element was correctly located and assigned.

Answer (score 0):

Please check with any one of the below option.

1.First Check whether the Checkbox is Enabled or not. If it is enabled, then perform click action as below

```
    WebElement pageElement = driver.findElement(by);
    if(pageElement.isEnabled()){
        pageElement.click();
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Checkbox is not Enabled");
    }
```

2. Check the Checkbox Locator and If it is correct, just highlight the element in UI for debugging

```
    WebElement pageElement = driver.findElement(by);

    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', arguments[1]);", pageElement, "color: red; border: 2px solid yellow;");
```

Comment: Tried checking that it's not enabled. I am able to locate and assign the element because .getAttribute() returns the correct value. It's just the .click() that doesn't happen.

Comment: If the checkbox is enabled, then only you can perform the click action. As per your comments, check box is not enabled So, you can't perform the click action on the disabled checkbox

Comment: If the checkbox element is enabled, then you can either select or unselect the checkbox and If it is disabled, then you can't perform any of the action. Can you confirm , whether you are able to select /unselect the checkbox manually in UI

Comment: My mistake. I confused isEnabled with isSelected.